# How to Import xPath fields of XML to Pimcore DataDirector dataport raw data fields?

Tags: import, pimcore, data-mapping, datadirector

Pimcore has powerfull plugin DataDirector for import automation.
It proposes manual configuration of fields to import and their mapping to Pimcore fields https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyhKJTzTq-4&list=PL4-QRNfdsdKIfzQIP-c9hRruXf0r48fjt

It works fine if you have 10-50 fields.
How to import that configuration from some csv file whan you have 700+ fields?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to import using interface of commandline DataDirector API.

I tried to request such functionality creation from vendor -- it costs.

I tried to edit it in MySQL but it is strictly coupled to other data, see: SELECT sourceconfig FROM `plugin_pim_dataport`;

**Solution:**

Each dataport can be exported and imported to JSON. This is our chance.

1. create sample dataport using your source XML
2. export it to sample.json
3. unserialize $json_a['plugin_pim_dataport']['sourceconfig'] and $json_a['plugin_pim_rawitemField'] containers

   ```
        $string = file_get_contents(
            "sample.json"
        );
        $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
        $sourceConfig = $json_a['plugin_pim_dataport']['sourceconfig'];
        $sourceConfig = unserialize($sourceConfig, ['allowed_classes' => false]);

        $fieldsConfig = $json_a['plugin_pim_rawitemField'];
   ```
4. add new fields to them from any source e.g. CSV

   ```
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
            $row++;
            $id = $max + 1 + $row;
            $data = $this->addField($id, $data[0], $data[1]);
            $sourceConfig['fields']['field_' . ($id + 1)] = $data['sourceConfig'];
            $fieldsConfig[$id] = $data['fieldsConfig'];
        }

    public function addField(
        $id,
        $name = 'ObjectBrick/Field',
        $xpath = '//*[.//MainContainer = "systeme"]//*[.//Description = "SomeAttribute"]/anyPath/SampleContainer'
    ) {
        $res = [];

        $res['fieldsConfig'] = [
            "dataportId" => "1",
            "fieldNo"    => $id + 1,
            "name"       => $name,
            "priority"   => $id
        ];
        $res['sourceConfig'] = [
            'xpath'       => $xpath,
            'multiValues' => false,
        ];

        return $res;
    }
   ```
5. serialize, save to JSON, import to your dataport.